# Swift UI Queues and DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: swift, multithreading, scenekit, dispatch-async, dispatch-queue

I'm currently building a game in Swift that overlays a 'd-pad' and various other items such as a score label and start label on the game itself.

Those items are set up in an SCNView, while the game itself, consisting of a ship and tunnel, is built within a UIViewController.

I began running into a UI threading error when I implemented a 'reset' function in the UIViewController, which rebuilds the game by calling functions from both the SCNView and UIViewController. I managed to fix almost all of the errors by enclosing all the code that displays the error in DispatchQueue.main.async, however am still left with just this one bad piece of code:

```
var gameView: GameView { 
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        return self.view as! GameView
    }
}
```

With this code, it tells me 1. "Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'GameView'" and 2. "Cannot convert value of type 'GameView' to closure result type 'Void'".

Can anyone inform me what is wrong here exactly, and why? If not blatantly obvious, this is a portion of Swift that I really am not knowledgable of.

Further than that, I can't help but think I built this whole game pretty inefficiently, if anyone more experienced is able to shed some light on how they would of went about coding this, it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks everyone.